# Change UI elements of and APK file

Tags: java, android, xml, editor

I made an Android application a while ago. Now i moved to Python. All I have of my old Android project is the APK file that built back then.
Looking at it now i do not like the way that the UI looks. So i want to edit some elements.
To do that i used a Linux machine to decompile(disassemble) the APK file using ApkTool. Now i have a bunch of folders and whatnot.
My question came when i tried to view the XML code of the decompiled APK and have a preview of the current UI on the other side of my screen (you know how android studio does it). is there any way that i can get a software of any kind that lets me convert my APK file into a 100% Android project. i just want to change a few UI elements.
Going into the res/layout folder that got generated and looking at the XML files, i feel like those are not really the UI files that i would have normally worked on in Android Studio.
Plus, installing Android Studio is pretty tiresome (i have experience with that). So is there any other software that can do what i want? i would prefer if it was on a Linux machine. But windows is okay too.
So to simplify my question: Is there any way that i can disassemble an APK file, view its layout files (XML) and make some changes to the layout elements (buttons and whatnot)?

I literally spent hours every day trying to find a solution to this online. I even asked ChatGPT and BARD. I am stuck as stuck can ever get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.